# Stop tilde expansion in bash script arguments

Tags: bash, shell, tilde-expansion

Consider this tiny script:

```
# script.sh
echo $@
```

If I call it like this `./script.sh ~/docs`, I get `/home/me/docs` as output. However, I need it to echo `~/docs`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `echo ${1/$HOME/\~}` Using the parameter-expansion with text replacement to replace the directories `/home/youruser` from the first program argument with `~`. You can use the `$HOME` variable that contains `/home/youruser` in the expansion to make it generally apply to any user. You must escape the `~` with `\~` to prevent further tilde expansion by the shell.

Comment: The tilde-expansion does not happen in your script, but on the calling side. There is no way to find out how exactly the caller typed the command line invoking your program; you see only what the shell passes to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not under the script's control. It's up to the user. They must quote the tilde to prevent it from being expanded. Options include:

```
./script.sh \~/docs
./script.sh '~/docs'
./script.sh "~"/docs
```